How to make the scipy minimization function multithread?
I try to use scipy minimize to solve a minimization functions. My objective function and gradient function require multi-threaded computation. However, when calling these functions, there is no parallel or multithreaded execution, where there is when I run them not in scipy minimization. Here is my code:
def objective_and_gradient (ks_flat):

    u_now, data_error_norm = heat_solver (ks_flat)
    r_delta, ks_delta, k0_delta = D_adjoint (ks_flat)
    grad = ks_delta / np.linalg.norm (ks_delta) * np.linalg.norm (ks_flat) * 0.001
    return data_error_norm, grad

result = minimize (
    fun = objective_and_gradient,
    x0 = ks_initial,
    method = 'BFGS',
    jac = True, 
    options = {'maxiter': N_k, 'disp': True})

Here the functions heat_solver and D_adjoint are multithreaded. They are fenics programming to solver heat equations.
I want to know that if scipy minimization is able to run in a multithreaded way. If it is, how to do it?

Starting multiple threads, scheduling them on available core, possibly wait for cores to wake-up, join threads and gather results from other caches is expensive at small grain. This is even more true with CPython processes which are heavy (CPython threads are limited by the GIL) and results in very expensive IPC operations. Thus, your objective function needs to be both particularly expensive per call and CPU-bound (not memory-bound). If your objective function takes <100 µs, then it probably not worth it (at least not with CPython).

@
Jérôme Richard
Thanks for your comments! In fact my objective function takes more than 1min, so I think it is necessary to use all available cores. My objective function uses MPI and I think that it uses all available cores because I use the command "MPI.COMM_WORLD". However, when I run scipy minimize and call these functions, they only use one thread.

Ok 1 minute per call is a lot indeed. The thing is MPI should already use all the core if used properly. While hybrid application using both MPI processes and multiple thread can sometimes be faster, the benefice is rather small and in Python there is a good chance it will be slower because CPython threads are limited by the GIL. Indeed, using more threads means less process per node (otherwise this typically results in over-subscription which make things much slower). CPython's multiprocessing make no sense with MPI. I assume you use as many MPI processes as cores though.

MPI.COMM_WORLD is for communicators and not the use of core or nodes. For the later, you need to tune a hostfile or tweak the mpirun cmdline or possibly use a MPI-aware job submission system (it depends of your setup/platform). For Also be careful if you use MPI in the objective function then the optimization algorithm should be done one process only unless you replicate data to all MPI processes (which is certainly sub-optimal).

By the way BFGS should use multiple threads already AFAIK so you might already have over-subscription issues if you run as many MPI processes as cores.

@JérômeRichard "BFGS should use multiple threads already" My understanding is that none of the scipy.optimize.minimize solvers call the objective function in parallel. I don't see any multithreading in the BFGS implementation. Some BLAS operations might be multithreaded, but if evaluating the objective function takes a minute, I imagine those are not the bottleneck.

@NickODell Yes, the objective function is never called in parallel (it would not be sane due to the GIL). I talked about the internal minimization algorithm itself. I said that because last time I profiled a BFGS minimization script, a significant time was spent in parallel computation (IDK what was computed during this time). Meanwhile, the objective function was a basic sequential operation (AFAIR no BLAS code in it but it was some time ago so not 100% sure either). I need to check this again.
